# Get the value of an Angular button and log them into the console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a very basic question.

I have two buttons in my view, what I want to do is to assign the value of each of those buttons to a variable in my controller (**"$scope.buttonValue"**, ***for example***) so every time I click on each I can log the value in the console and give the `$scope` variable a value depending on the button I click.

## Basic Angular Buttons

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-init="showData = 1">
  <button ng-model="showData" type="button" ng-class='{"btn btn-primary": showData == 1, "btn btn-white": showData != 1}' ng-click="showData = 1">One</button>
  <button ng-model="showData" type="button" ng-class='{"btn btn-primary":showData == 2, "btn btn-white": showData != 2}'  ng-disabled="!loadViewOne" ng-click="showData = 2">Two</button>
</div>
```

[Basic Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/UQao1VKFAWP9Mef3oCvk)

I'm new to angular and js so I need some help on this to understand more stuff.

The buttons have some validations, and I think I'm already giving a value to showData, but I don't know how to pass that to a `$scope` in a controller.

Comment: As you have done ng-model=showData, this will automatically attached to $scope. In your serviceCall method, try loging/alerting $scope.showData

Comment: You are not calling any method in ng-click for the first button btw. Apart from the above answer, you could even pasd the value from html on click ng-click=serviceCall(showData)

Comment: Thanks for your time, but assuming I remove the service call method.. (actually that's not important) as @Developer said, it's already attached to $scope right?

Comment: Yes, it is. showData will be available in $scope of controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would change your Plunkr example code to work.

[See it on Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/UQao1VKFAWP9Mef3oCvk?p=preview)

First of all, I would change `showData` to be a function that the `ng-click` expressions call. This allows you to actually respond to the click of the button by doing stuff in your controller. In my code, this function just sets a separate property on the scope, which I called `data`, that is used for other logic like the button classes.

Here it is as a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.data = 1;
  $scope.loadViewBrands = true;

  $scope.showData = function(num) {
    $scope.data = num;
  };

  $scope.summaryCall = function() {
    $scope.summaryCallText = 'summaryCall() was run, and data = ' + $scope.data;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.summaryCallText = '';
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Basic Angular Buttons</h1>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" ng-class="{'btn btn-primary': data == 1, 'btn btn-white': data != 1}" ng-click="showData(1)">One</button>
      <button type="button" ng-class="{'btn btn-primary':data == 2, 'btn btn-white': data != 2}" ng-disabled="!loadViewBrands" ng-click="showData(2); summaryCall()">Two</button>
    </div>
    <p>data = {{data}}</p>
    <div class="alert alert-info" ng-if="summaryCallText">
      {{summaryCallText}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time =)